# Access Neustar API using scalasca

Tags: scala, rest, api

I am new to both scala and Neustar. I currently have this documentation as my reference: https://ipintelligence.neustar.biz/portal/#documentation but this does not mention any sample code on how to call this API using scala.

Does anyone have any pointers on this? Or maybe just in general on how to access a rest api using scala?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use STTP Client. This blogpost is a good start: https://softwaremill.com/introducing-sttp-the-scala-http-client/

DISCLAIMER: I work for SoftwareMill, which is creator of STTP.